# how to perform a post request just like the browser to get the same results

Tags: python, http, post, https, python-requests

I have this webpage: https://www.dsbmobile.de. I would like to automate a bot that checks in and gets the newest file. I have an account and login credentials so I tried this with python:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.dsbmobile.de/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f"

payload = {'txtUser': 'username', 'txtPass': 'password'}

x = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(x.text)
```

I get a result but its just the login page instead of the new page I should be ridirected to .
When looking at the source, I saw that there are hidden input fields such as "__EVENTVALIDATION"
do I need to send them too? Or maybe I need to set something into the header idk. It would be very nice if someone could tell me how to write the post request just like the browser sends it so that I get the right response

I am new but it would be extremely useful to me if I could automate that process.

Thank you very much for trying to help me

Comment: If you're logging into a service, you'll have to setup a session (to be able to save the cookies that are returned). The requests library also handles this session creation for you. As far as what other fields you should be using to login, you'll probably want to open your dev tools in a browser and see what values are sent when you login. This would be on the networking tab of most browsers I believe.

Comment: its hard for me to identify the right things.. can you maybe explain a little better what you mean by values

Comment: Values as in the values your browser is sending with the login request. "__EVENTVALIDATION" may be one of them, it depends on the website really. You may not even need them. If you use your browser's dev tools, under the networking tab (in firefox) it shows you every request that is made, and it will include all the information that is sent, including values in the body and any headers.You may need to search for a bit to find the exact request, but they allow you to filter pretty easily as well.

Comment: thank you very much I will try that